# How To Highlight Rows Based On Multiple Cell Values In Excel?

Tags: excel

I'm using Excel 2016, and I want to highlight all rows based on multiple cell values, what I'm trying to do is to highlight rows where a cell contains the text "page" or "list", I tried as following :

[image]

But this didn't work !

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula should be local. In French `OR` should be `OU`, in order to make it run.

See here for translation of the formulas - http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/

Comment: I tried `OU` but I'm getting the same warning message dialog

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki - It may also need semicolons instead of commas, `=OU($B2="page";$B2="list")`